# Removing desired character from a String (From a String or char[])

Tags: java

### Removing desired character from a String (From a String or char[])

I've searched around the Java sections but haven't found an adequate answer. I'm testing out some basic *(extremely basic)* object obscuring for serialization just to get the feel of it.

---

To de-obscure my object I need to remove the added character that I've put on my object.

E.g

> Profile name is original "John"
>
> I then turn it into, "#J/oH@n"

I would then need to reverse the latter into the original by removing the symbols. However I couldn't find a suitable/efficient way of doing so.

---

Please do keep in mind that my list of symbols could be saved in char[] or just one String like so:

```
char[] obcChars = {'#', ';', '"', '¬', '¦', '+', ';'
        , '/', '.', '^', '&', '$', '*'
        , '[', '@', '-', '~', ':'};

String s = new String(obcChars);
```

Whichever method you need to use to facilitate your answer is fine by me! I'd also like to thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a regular expression which contains the characters you want to remove:

```
    char[] obcChars = {'#', ';', '"', '¬', '¦', '+', ';'
            , '/', '.', '^', '&', '$', '*'
            , '[', '@', '-', '~', ':'};
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(obcChars[0]);
    for (int i=1; i<obcChars.length; i++) {
        sb.append("|\\");
        sb.append(obcChars[i]);
    }
    // sb now contains the regex #|\;|\"|\¬|\¦|\+|\;|\/|\.|\^|\&|\$|\*|\[|\@|\-|\~|\:
```

Then just use the `String#replaceAll()` method to take them out of your input string:

```
    String oName = "#J/oH@n";
    System.out.println(oName.replaceAll(sb.toString(), "")); // prints JoHn
```

### Note

This will be useful if you know which characters you want to remove, and they are a limited subset of non-alpha.  If you just want to trim out all non-letters, see @alfasin's answer for a much simpler solution to that problem.

Comment: Thanks azure for the comment, I'll try out your method as the above one seems to be throwing me a Pattern exception of some sort(An error from my side)

Comment: Can confirm that this method works just fine, will test it multiple times and confirm the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

To remove characters at an index from a String you have to use a StringBuilder which is a mutable version of a String (you can change StringBuilders)

```
String s = "Hello World";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
sb.removeCharAt(sb.indexOf('e'));
s = sb.toString();
System.out.println(s); // Prints Hllo World
```

Comment: So if I know the EXACT index numbers of where the symbols are, I may use that method?

Comment: If you don't know exact index numbers you can use `indexOf()`

Comment: Glad I could help, make sure you accept the answer if you think it answers the question :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex:

```
    String obcChars = "[^a-zA-Z]";
    String word = "#J/oH@n";
    word = word.replaceAll(obcChars, "");
    System.out.println("word = " + word);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
word = JoHn
```

Comment: Hmm seems to be throwing an exception stating that: Unclosed character class near index 16
#;"¬¦+;/.^&$*[@-~  -  PatternSyntaxException, I presume this has to do with the char[] obcChars

Comment: @Juxhin there's no `char[]` in the code and I don't use ` #;"¬¦+;/.^&$*` either

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake! Thanks alfasin

Comment: @Juxhin no worries :)